# Ocelot not forwarding the body of the request

Tags: asp.net, ocelot

I built a very simple gateway with ocelot. In my architecture for now, users can request a token by sending a post request (containing the credentials in the body) through the gateway which will redirect it to the correct endpoint. The problem is that the body is not being forwarded correctly.
This is how my ocelot configuration file looks:

```
{
   "Routes": [
     {
       "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/token",
       "DownstreamScheme": "https",
       "DownstreamHttpMethod": "Post",
       "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
         {
           "Host": "myhost.com",
           "Port": 443
         }
       ],
       "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/token",
       "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
         "Post"
       ],          
       "FileCacheOptions": {
         "TtlSeconds": 0,
         "Region": ""
       },

       "RateLimitOptions": {        
         "ClientWhitelist": [],
         "EnableRateLimiting": true,                    
         "Period": "20s",
         "PeriodTimespan": 30,
         "Limit": 5
       }    
     }
   ],
   "GlobalConfiguration": {
     "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:5000",
     "RateLimitOptions": {
       "DisableRateLimitHeaders": false,
       "QuotaExceededMessage": "Customize exceeded message!",
       "HttpStatusCode": 999,          
       "ClientIdHeader": "headerUsername"
     }
   }
 }
```

And this is how the ocelot middleware configuration in my Startup.cs file looks like:

```
var configuration = new OcelotPipelineConfiguration
{
       PreErrorResponderMiddleware = async (ctx, next) =>
       {                     
           if (ctx.Request.Path == "/token")
           {
               // Test to read the body
               var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(ctx.Request.ContentLength)];
               await ctx.Request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
               string bodyAsText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
                   
               JObject jsonCredentials = JObject.Parse(bodyAsText);                                                   
               await next.Invoke();
          }                      
       }          
 };

 app.UseOcelot(configuration);
```

I already looked at https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot/issues/792 which talks about the same problem that i have but it seems a bit outdated. Does anyone who how to make so that the body gets forwarded too? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `PreErrorResponderMiddleware` doesn't return anything when the path is not `/token` - is this intended?

Comment: Yes i'm aware of that. Since right now i'm only testing the ocelot functionalities, i wanted to make sure that the problem i'm facing was clear and i left only the **/token** path in the code. Anyway i managed to workaround the issue with delegating handlers. I might answer my own question later.